# Dervish of Dawn (Fighter) reducing higher charge AC penalties

Tags: pathfinder-1e, armor-class, archetype, charge

> [Burst of Speed](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/fighter/archetypes/paizo-fighter-archetypes/dawnflower-dervish/) (Ex)
>
> At 3rd level, a dervish takes only a –1 penalty to her AC after charging. At 7th level, the dervish can charge with no penalty.
>
> This ability replaces Armor Training 1.

-

How does this interact with feats and abilities that increase the AC penalty of charging, such as a [Savage Warrior](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/fighter/archetypes/paizo-fighter-archetypes/savage-warrior/)'s Savage Charge, or the [Sliding Dash](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/sliding-dash-combat/) feat? Would it completely remove the penalty, or only reduce it by two, or should it be ruled to reduce it by 1 + 1 for every four levels past 3rd?

I suppose the same could be asked of the [Nimble Striker](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/racial-feats/nimble-striker-combat-catfolk/) feat as well.

Answer (score 1):

Both Sliding Dash and the 3rd level part of Burst of Speed replace the penalty with a new one so I'm not sure which of those would apply. Savage Charge, on the other hand just increases the penalty so it would stack with either of the two others.

But at 7th level it instead lets you choose to not take an AC penalty which is different than replacing the value of that penalty. So for levels 3-6 I don't know what would happen, but at 7+ you wouldn't have a penalty.

Comment: Hi Julian, welcome to the site! You may want to take the [tour].